# Ubuntu 14.04 cannot unlock "user accounts" panel

Tags: 14.04, unity, metacity

Already happened time ago but I cannot remember the solution (remove some  in home directory, I think).

I cannot unlock some panels like the "User Accounts" even though I am an administrator.

[image]

Also since yesterday, after an update, I am forced to use Unity as the metacity session shows an empty desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what could be the reason maybe it's a bug.

But as a workaround for you to do your work you can run it previously unlocked using command line

```
sudo gnome-control-center user-accounts
```

Comment: Thanks but I know how to bypass the problem. I'd like to know **why** it's happening. Anyway it must have something to do with lightdm because switching to gdm solved all, also the session problem. But, of course, also my solution is not a good answer as it doesn't explain why.

Comment: @marco You are welcome. I hoped to help